# Does Laravel Auth have intuitive error messages?

Tags: laravel-4

I am working to implement authentication with Laravel's built-in Auth.

I've looked over the tutorials and S.O. boards.

They recommend various ways to set up validation, but I haven't seen one that references native errors from the Auth script that explain why Auth failed.

I can't find them in Auth either.

---

Working through the app I found the following in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/auth/console/stubs/controller.stub

```
    /**
 * Handle a POST request to reset a user's password.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function postReset()
{
    $credentials = Input::only(
        'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
    );

    $response = Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password)
    {
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);

        $user->save();
    });

    switch ($response)
    {
        case Password::INVALID_PASSWORD:
        case Password::INVALID_TOKEN:
        case Password::INVALID_USER:
            return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));

        case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
            return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

Working on an implementation building on this.

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific message. Authentication will either pass or fail.

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials))
{
    // Authentication succeeded!
}
else
{
    // Invalid credentials.
}
```

So you can't specifically tell the user that it was their username that was incorrect.

Comment: Can Auth be extended to describe why it failed?